# How to get an array of information from a Doctrine ORM database

Tags: orm, doctrine, zend-framework2

I have recently started working with Doctrine ORM and I am struggling with the holistic idea of how to get an array of information from a database.

Typically I would do something like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Users";
$userArray = $this->db->fetchAll($sql);
```

I am able to use setters and getters to update information using my Entity... I have absolutely no clue how to go about using entites to grab information from the DB...

This is what I have:

Controller:

```
   public function usersAction() {
   $userFunctions = new UserFunction;
   $userArray = $userFunctions->getUsers();
   $viewModel = new ViewModel(array('users' => $userArray));
   return $viewModel;
```

UserFunction:

```
<?php

namespace Administration\Model;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Zend\Paginator\Paginator;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager;

class UserFunction
{
protected $entityManager;
protected $em;

function __constructor(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager) {
    $this->em = $entityManager;
}

public function getUsers()
{
    //Do some DB fetching magic and return user list in an array
    return array(1,2,3,4,5);
}

}
```

If you can suggest the HOW to fetch the DATA using ORM Doctrine, that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data will be returned as an array of entities:

Your "getUsers()" method might look like this:

```
/**
 * Returns an array of User entities.
 */
public function getUsers()
{
    return $this->em->getRepository('My\Entity\User')->findAll();
}
```

The method returns an array of objects (specifically, objects of class \My\Entity\User).

In your view script, you might do something like:

```
<h1>All Users</h1>
<?php foreach($users as $u): ?>
<?= $u->getUsername(); ?><br/>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

---

So, when you ask about "go about using entites to grab information from the DB...", what you really want to do is "use the EntityManager (and/or EntityRepositories) to grab *entities* from the DB".

Remember: Entities themselves don't know about persistence (the DB).  But the EntityManager and Repositories do.

Finally, based on this question, and another of yours I answered, I suggest you take a look at Repositories in Doctrine.  You seem to be reinventing that wheel to some degree.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I add that line I get the following error: Fatal error: Call to protected Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager::__construct(). In my IDEA when I hover over the getRepository method it throws this error: "Method getRepository not found in class (referenced method it not found in subject class). Any idea what or why this is being thrown... been struggling with this for a few hours now :S

Comment: That's probably because you are not actually injecting your entitymanager.  Your constructor isn't running because it should be name __construct(), not __constructor().

Comment: Ahh ok new error: Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Administration\Model\UserFunction::__construct() must be an instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager, none given... the EM really confuses me...

Comment: I don't think the EM is what's really confusing you.  It's not all that complicated.  I think what's tripping you up is the ServiceManager.  Your new error is happening because whatever code is creating your "UserFunction" class isn't passing in an EntityManager.  Are you using DoctrineORMModule (you should be)?

Comment: Yes you are right - I added this: $em = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager'); $userFunctions = new UserFunction($em); which appears to work. Thanks!